# IntelliJ Merge Revision does not highlights differences and neither let me modify the files

Tags: intellij-idea, merge, git-merge

Hello everyone and thanks in advance, so , my IntelliJ is does not highlight the differences when i try to merge two branches together. Basically i've been working in GitHub with a friend of mine but when we try to merge stuff there are always problems. I've been doing pull and merge correctly i think, but when i press "Merge..." in IntelliJ, it opens the Merge Revision interface but does not make me modify files because it says that they are in "read only", which is not true.

I just noticed that we are using JDK 19 and JDK 21, could that be the problem?

I've tried to modify Maven dependencies but nothing happened, i've tried to verify permits but it wasn't that either. I've tried to uninstall IntelliJ and reinstall it but nothing worked. It does the same stuff to my friend too.

Last thing i want to try is to make her modify her JDK to 21.

I'll update this post when she does it

Comment: Please explain what you are doin when you say " I've been doing pull and merge correctly i think,".

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering, i'm doing exactly what you see in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgipWkaU2MM&ab_channel=IntelliJIDEAbyJetBrains

Answer (score 0):

It's best to reach out to Intelij support with screenshots and logs of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'll do that